# Clear Case to SVN migration

Tags: svn, clearcase, version-control-migration

We are planing to migration our projects version controlled by clear case into SVN. And I have tried the SVNImporter which is provided by polarion. Its ok for small vob migration. But when the vob is larger (200mb), I will get the heap out of memory error (I have set the -Xmx = 1024m ), and it is slow to do that process.

Any one has some experience on CC to SVN migration and known some other open source tools which will work for large clearcase vobs? Or any suggestion/best practice can share with will be much appreciated.

Update: we need the history of files, branch, tag on clear case

Comment: you can migrate one by one directory instead of everything in one go.

Comment: @Ved there may be handreds of directories inside of our clear case view directory.

Comment: You have to take immediate directory not all the child nodes. This is some what similar to what is written in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround would be to try and make the import **incremental** wuith the [SVNImporter](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer.php).

For instance, import only a part of the [cc2svn dumped vob](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer_features.php#CC) (by top sub-folders, which is useful if those folders represents a component): one svn repo per component can be easier to manage (and import) than a giant svn repo.

Comment: did you mean when I run the svnimporter, do not specify the top clear case directory in the configuration file as the source, specify the sub directory one by one?

Comment: @user1311839 yes, because I don't remember if if you can do this on the cc2svn side, meaning dumping only part of a ClearCase Vob.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Btw is there any other open source tools you know about which might be better?

Comment: @user1311839 not to my knowledge, no. I usually don't migrate the full history, and keep the ClearCase vob around for read-only access.

Comment: so the best practice is keep the history and data still in the clear case, checkout the latest version in clear case and check into SVN ?

Comment: @user1311839 yes, it is the most convenient one at least.

Comment: I forgot to ask after I migration one folder by one. How can I merge then together?

Comment: @user1311839 If you are using ClearCase UCM, you would make a project in which you add all the UCM components you have created from the imported SVN folders.

Comment: Hi VonC, we don't use this UCM feature.In this case, what should I do?

Comment: @user1311839 simply use a config spec which select the right versions for the different folders of your Vobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one https://github.com/ghusse/cc2svn

I did Migrated Huge repo size ~150 GB to SVN using the above tool. It will migrate with history but you will get only the modified files on that particular branch. So here what i did.

1. Migrated the branches to svn with history (got only modified files).
2. Now, take a full source of the whole branch in Clearcase
3. Checkout the Migrated branch in SVN and Overwrite the Sources from Clearcase.

Now, in point 3 --> You will get a base sources apart from modified files, but the revision will be one more for base source (should be fine in my case, since i will commit saying that its a base source during commit).